# Lock a Application Through Terminal

Tags: shell, terminal, osx, application, lock

I was wondering if it were possible to lock a Application through Mac Terminal. I know there's a way to lock files, using chmod a+x 000 'directory', but it never worked with an Application. What I mean is, I can still run and use the Application freely. If I must delete the application instead, please tell me because rm is for specific files and there is no way to delete a directory as far as I know. (rm -rmdir doesn't work).

Thanks for the help,
   Jack

Comment: `chmod a-x` works fine with applications for me (as does `rm -r`). What do you mean when you say it doesn't work? You can [edit] your post with more details.

Comment: That's the answer! sudo chmod a-x /Application/'Whatever Application' worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Michael Homer answered my question. The code is:

```
sudo chmod a-x /Applications/'Whatever Application'
```

The code works perfectly and the Application cannot be opened.